# Get inner html of the component as a variable in vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Say I have a vuejs component called `child-component` which is added to a parent component as follows.

```
<child-component>
  <div>Hello</div>
</child-component>
```

N.B. this is not the template of the child component. This is how the child component is added to the parent.

How can I get the innerHTML, i.e. `<div>Hello</div>` in the child component as a string?

Comment: Do you mean, the actual non-parsed html in the slot? Also, where do you want to "get" it?

Comment: As a data variable in the component

Comment: *WHY* are you doing this? You shouldn't have to do this in 99% of situations.

Comment: @BillCriswell in my case, I'm getting a bunch of html from a Component library I'm using, and there's one specific element that's created with it but not directly accessible and I'd like to add html to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the component, `child-component`, the HTML would be available in the `mounted` lifecycle handler as `this.$el.innerHTML`. The parsed vnodes would be available from `this.$slots.default`.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("child-component",{
  template: `<div><slot/></div>`,
  mounted(){
    console.log("HTML", this.$el.innerHTML)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child-component>
    <div>Hello</div>
  </child-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at using Vue Child Component Refs.  That will let you access the child component's innerHTML from the parent component.

Just add a ref attribute to your child component. It can be anything you choose:

```
<child-component ref="mychildcomponent">
   <div>Hello</div>
</child-component>
```

Then in the parent methods, you can do something like:

```
let childEl = this.$refs.mychildcomponent
```

That will set childEl the entire child component that you've referenced.  To get the innerHTML youd just have to go a little further, and do something like this:

```
let childEl = this.$refs.mychildcomponent.$el.innerHTML
```

That should give you a string of the child component's innerHTML.

This might help: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs

Alternatively if you want to get it from the child component itself, just do the following within a method:

```
let componentHTML = this.$el.innerHTML
```

Hope that helps.